# CATransform3D UIView animateWithDuration sequence

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, catransform3d

I'm a Core Animation beginner trying to animate a view in 3D sequentially.  However, I'm running into issues with the 2nd animation.  Essentially, once the view rotates and translates to a certain point, I'm making another translation.

When I run it, it seems like it's working, but the second animation translates the view to its destination but then returns to its initial position!  It is as if a 3rd phantom animation happens to return the view to its initial state.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?
Thank you!

```
CATransform3D translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, -50.0, 0.0);
translation.m34 = 1.0 / -500.0f;
CATransform3D finalTransform = CATransform3DRotate(translation, 90.0f, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
    [viewImageScroll.layer setTransform:finalTransform];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    CATransform3D flyAway = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0., 0., -10000);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f animations:^{
        NSLog(@"done");
        [viewImageScroll.layer setTransform:flyAway];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"done and done");
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Turns out this has to do with m34. Changing its value resulted in a different animation in Z axis. Don't understand why it would make the translation of z go back to its initial position halfway through the 2nd animation.

Comment: Alright, figured it out, you need to set up your perspective before you make your transforms.

Comment: CAKeyframeAnimation will most likely be cleaner code than nesting UIView blocks like you are doing.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but CAKeyframeAnimation doesn't provide a completion callback?

Comment: CATransaction does provide a completion callback using a block and being a delegate to the animation gives you the animationDidFinish callback. Corrected?